# Black window when navigating from App delegate in xamarin Ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, navigation

I'm getting a black window after navigating to a view controller. My app is calling a page from app delegate from the OpenUrl method.

```
 public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, string sourceApp, NSObject annotation)
    {
        var rurl = new Rivets.AppLinkUrl(url.ToString());
       // navController = new UINavigationController();
        var id = string.Empty;


        if (rurl.InputQueryParameters.ContainsKey("id"))
            id = rurl.InputQueryParameters["id"];

        if (rurl.InputUrl.Host.Equals("products") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            // var mainController = new UIViewController();

           // NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(true, "ForgotPwdLinkClicked");
           return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //var c = new ProductViewController();
            // UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = c; 
            var c = new UpdatePasswordViewController();
           navigationController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen;
           navigationController.PushViewController
                (c, true);
            //// return true ;
            ///*this.Window.RootViewController =
            //    c;*/
           // NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(true, "ForgotPwdLinkClicked");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

These are my ViewController settings in XCode:

[image: this is the Property of the page]
[image: This is the image of the View which i want to call]

Comment: Your example seems similar to the [default example](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-ios/) so, have you correctly setup `navigationController` variable in `FinishedLaunching` ?

Comment: yes i added @Nerkyator

`private UINavigationController navigationController;
var rootController =
                        UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", NSBundle.MainBundle)
                            .InstantiateViewController("LoginView");
                      navigationController = new UINavigationController(rootController) {NavigationBarHidden = true};

                      this.Window.RootViewController = navigationController;`


this is the navigationController controller

Comment: Uhm...cannot try right now but: In storyboard set `NavigationController` as Initial view controller and embed your login UIViewController in it. In `OpenUrl` method just cast `this.Window.RootViewController` to `UINavigationController` and `PushViewController` as in your sample (sorry for not providing a working example but I cannot try right now, I hope this will give you an idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code resolve my issue

```
 UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null);// this will bee our storyboard name 
var c = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("UpdatePasswordViewController") as UpdatePasswordViewController;
```